# Open File-Intent in all devices through the same code or by applying any logic

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-intentservice, android-storage

I want to choose a file via an Android File Manager.

so, to open file intent code is

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("file/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select File"), 1);
```

But I was unable to access file manager in samsung devices to resolve this problem i do

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
intent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "*/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

But this code in not working in other devices so what should i do to open file manager in all devices ?

Comment: "I want to choose a file via an Android File Manager" -- not all devices have a "file manager" app installed. "should i do to open file manager in all devices ?" -- use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` (or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` on Android 4.4+). Or, [use a file chooser library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35). Also, `file/*` is not a valid MIME type.

Comment: not working in samsung devices by using ACTION_GET_CONTENT (or ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT @CommonsWare

Comment: Please explain in detail what "not working" means.

Comment: didnt get my files option @CommonsWare

Comment: Please explain **in detail** what "didnt get my files option" means.

Comment: only gallery and other option shows but i want to select from file manager @CommonsWare

Comment: There may not be a file manager on that device. Many devices do not ship with a file manager. The standard `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` UI shows a few locations by default, and accessing "internal files" is available via the overflow menu.

Comment: but using Intent intent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
intent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "*/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);   this code i got acees to file manager but problem is this is not working in other devices @CommonsWare

Comment: Correct. That is an undocumented, unsupported `Intent` action that will be available on some Samung devices (see `com.sec` in the action string). While Samsung is a popular manufacturer, their devices are a small percentage of the ~2 billion devices (and ~10,000 device models).

Comment: so please suggest me common solution so that would work on all devices @CommonsWare

Comment: I did. Use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` (or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` on Android 4.4+). Or, use a [file chooser library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35). You cannot force device manufacturers to add a file manager to their devices. You cannot force device manufacturers to document and support a common `Intent` structure for accessing their file managers. You cannot force users to install file managers. So, either work with the standard `Intent` actions in Android, or use a library that ships with your app.

Comment: okay , I got it Thank you sir @CommonsWare

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.user.rathod/files/document/primary:DCIM/Camera/20170927_183338.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) @CommonsWare

Comment: caught this error thrown by samsung devices @CommonsWare

Comment: /document/primary:DCIM/Camera/20170927_183338.jpg This is image path

Comment: You do not get back a file. You get back a `Uri`. The use of a `Uri` is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#client), plus books and courses on Android app development. See also [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/03/storage-access-framework-faq.html) and [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html). If you have further concerns in this area, ask a fresh question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void openFile(int  requestCODE) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    i.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCODE);
}
```